# Converting project from offline to online project in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app written in Java in Android Studio. The app is offline; meaning that the user can open the app even if their device is not connected to the internet. I am wondering how to make the project online; meaning that it opens only if the user is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `onCreate` method you can check the network connectivity. If network is not available, you can exit application or whatever you want. Something like:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
          
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check for network connectivity
        if(!isConnectedToInternet())
        {
            // User is not connected to internet .You can exit app or display any message to user.
            this.finishAffinity();
        } 
    }
    
    public bool isConnectedToInternet()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                
        boolean connected = (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() ==  NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() ==     NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);

        return connected;

    
    }
```

You will need to add following permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Sir, did you mean onCreate method inside the mainactivity.java file?

Comment: Yes, inside your MainActivity.java file , you will be having an OnCreate method.  There you can write the  code as provided above.

Answer (score 0):

add condition if it's connected to internet or not as simple is that.. see this is the best answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out/27312494#27312494)